# can't get css3 drop down menu to appear on top of other elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button with a css3 drop down menu....I have tried several different ways of doing this....all have the problem that they are layered under the elements that follow....I have taken this code from examples on the web....in many of the examples the code appears in front...something is wrong with my code.....I think this is the z-index....but need some pointers on where to look for the problem.

If you look at the actions "button" when you hover over it the dropdown is behind the other code....

Here a pointer to the code on jsfiddle.
     http://jsfiddle.net/n3Zwm/

Here is the code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

<body>
 <div>
    <section>




<form action="/Vehicle/Info/VinInquiry" method="post">    <div class="divTable"  >
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"><label>VIN</label> </div>
        <div class="divTableCell">
              <input id="VIN" name="VIN" type="text" value="" />      
        </div>
         <div class="divTableCell"> <input type="submit"  value="Display" />  </div>



        <select name="Attachments">
            <option>Attach a File</option>
        </select>

        <div class="divTableCell"> <input type="submit"  value="Clear"  />  </div>
        <div class="divTableCell"> <input type="submit"  value="Email"  />  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTable">
   <div class="divTableRow">
       <div class="divTableCell">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Actions</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Add      Comment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Add      Allocation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Change   Allocation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cancel   Allocation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit     Dealer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Change   Hotrush Status</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Relocate Vehicle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Add      Service Request</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">????     Ship Voyage Entry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Goto     Process Manager</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cancel   WorkOrder          (Grid based)</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Change   WorkOrder Priority (Grid based)
                        </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Undo     WorkOrder          (Grid based  </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>




 <section>
 <div class="layer1">
    <p class="heading">General Vehicle Info (Status:  )</p>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="cols">
            <div class="col1">



                 <section class="chunk">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="hd">
                             <span class="text">Receiving Info</span>
                         </legend>


                        <div class="vinTable">
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Voyage: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Vessel: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label> (  )</label>    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Date: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Surveyed: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>

                    </fieldset>
                 </section>

                   <br />


                   <div class="group">
                        <div class="vinTable">
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Location: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Employee: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Date: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>

                  <br />


                   <div class="group">
                        <div class="vinTable">
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Carrier: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Load#: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label> - </label>    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Type: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Ramp: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">



                   <div class="group">
                       <div class="vinTable">
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Model: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Color: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Options: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>

                   <br />


                   <div class="group">
                       <div class="vinTable">
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Status: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>HotRush: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>BillTo: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>ShipTo: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Dealer: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Sales Type: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>AllocationDate: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>ShippingAuth: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label>0</label>  </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col3">


                   <div class="group">
                       <div class="vinTable">
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Category: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label> ()</label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Status: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label> - </label>    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Status: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label> - </label>  </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>

                   <br />


                   <div class="group">
                       <div class="vinTable">
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Pkn No: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Check8 Date: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Maint Ref Date: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Car Covered: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Factory SP: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Sp Installed: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>ProductionYN: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>ProdSchedDate: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col4">



                   <div class="group">
                       <div class="vinTable">
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Vin17: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Commission#: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label> (Yr: 0)</label>    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Archived Veh: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>Control Veh: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>ControlVehRecDate: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>ReleaseRecord: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>TentativeSchedDate: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="vinTableRow">
                                 <div class="labelTableCell"> <label>ServiceRequest: </label> </div>
                                 <div class="vinTableCell"> <label></label>  </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </section>


  </form>



  <style>
    .ScanVINTextBoxStyle3 { width: 180px; }
    .vinTable       { width: 100%; height:  10%; display: table; }
    .vinTableRow    { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table-row;}
    .labelTableCell { width: 50px; height: 100%; display: table-cell;}
    .vinTableCell   { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table-cell;}

    .group {border: solid thin; background: #EEEEEE; color: black; padding: 0.5em 1em; }

    .cols { width:1800px; }
    .col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 { width:350px; margin:0 5px; padding:10px; float:left; }




            .chunk {
                background:#ccf;
                border:0.2em solid #99c;
                border-top-left-radius:0.8em;
                border-top-right-radius:0.8em;
                display:block;
                margin-bottom:2em;
                overflow:hidden;
                position:relative;
            }
            .chunk fieldset {
                border:none;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            .chunk legend {
                border:none;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
                .chunk .hd {
                    display:block;
                    padding:0.5em 0 0.3em;
                    width:100%; /* For IE8 */
                }
                    .chunk .hd .text {
                        color:#003;
                        font-family:helvetica,arial;
                        font-size:138.5%;
                        font-weight:normal;
                        margin:0 0.5em;
                        white-space:normal;
                        display:block;zoom:1; /* For IE7 */
                    }
                .chunk .bd {
                    background: #eef;
                    border-top:0.2em solid #99c;
                    padding:1em 0.5em;
                }
                .chunk ol {
                    margin:0;
                    padding:0;
                }
                .chunk .fields li {
                    list-style-type:none;
                    margin-bottom:1em;
                    overflow:hidden;
                    position:relative;
                }
                .chunk .list li {
                    background:#edf;
                    color:#336;
                    padding:0.2em;
                }
                .chunk .list li:nth-child(2n) {
                    background:#dce;
                }
                .chunk .fields .label {
                    float:left;
                    font-size:108%;
                    width:25%;
                }
                .chunk .fields .field {
                    font-size:108%;
                    margin-left:30%;
                    padding-right:7px;
                    position:relative;
                }
                    .chunk .fields .field input[type=text]{
                        width:100%;
                    }
                    .chunk .fields .field.tiny input[type=text]{
                        width:5em;
                    }
                    .chunk .fields .field.date input[type=text]{
                        width:7em;
                    }
                    .chunk .fields .field.small input[type=text]{
                        max-width:17em;
                    }
                    .chunk .fields .field textarea {
                        height:6em;
                        width:100%;
                    }



    .layer1
     {
     margin  : 0;
     padding : 0;
     width   : 1550px;
     }

    .heading
    {
     margin          : 1px;
     color           : #fff;
     padding         : 3px 10px;
     cursor          : pointer;
     position        : relative;
     background-color: #c30;
    }

    .content
    {
     padding         : 5px 10px;
     background-color: #fafafa;
    }

   p
   {
     padding: 5px 0;
   }




  /*------------------------------------*\
    RESET
\*------------------------------------*/
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img{
    border:0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,th,var{
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
caption,th{
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after{
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym{
    border:0;
}




/*------------------------------------*\
    NAV
\*------------------------------------*/
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    /* Clear floats */
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    /* Bring the nav above everything else--uncomment if needed.
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    */
}
#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
#nav ul{
    background:#fff; /* Adding a background makes the dropdown work properly in IE7+. Make this as close to your page's background as possible (i.e. white page == white background). */
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); /* But! Let's make the background fully transparent where we can, we don't actually want to see it if we can help it... */
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; /* Introducing a padding between the li and the a give the illusion spaced items */
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; /* Stop text wrapping and creating multi-line dropdown items */
}
#nav li:hover ul{ /* Display the dropdown on hover */
    left:0; /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
}
#nav li:hover a{ /* These create persistent hover states, meaning the top-most link stays 'hovered' even when your cursor has moved down the list. */
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{ /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ /* Here we define the most explicit hover states--what happens when you hover each individual link. */
    background:#333;
}





.ScanVINTextBoxStyle3 { width: 180px; }
.divTable     { width: 35%; height:  10%; display: table; }
.divTableRow  { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table-row;}
.divTableCell { width: 25%;  height: 100%; display: table-cell;}
</style>



  </section>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes Sir it s the **z-index** just add it like this :

```
#nav li:hover ul {
left: 0;
z-index: 22222;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Zwm/10/